# Zero rows are returned after filter is applied in VBA

Tags: vba

I have 5 columns and when i apply filter on the field 1 and 2, it return different number of rows depending on the criteria.
I am using the following code

```
numberOfRows = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
```

But this doesnt work when 0 rows are returned. It gives 1 million odd as an answer.
How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numberOfRows = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
```